# Expo app crashes on when I use `npx expo start --no-dev` but runs fine with `npx expo start`

Tags: android, react-native, expo, dev-to-production

I have created a new expo app (react native). When I am running the app in --no-dev mode, the app is crashing without opening. But, the app runs perfectly fine in development mode. I am encountering this problem with every expo project I am creating.
Github repository link for one of my expo app is [repo](https://github.com/aashish-pandey/BusBookingApp/tree/main/MobileFrontEnd).

I am stuck with this problem for few days now. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you share the crash log?

Comment: sorry, but I don't know from where I can get this. Its like when I scan the QR code with my expo go app, the app doesn't open, it automatically closes and I return to the home screen of expo app.